# How to prove a statistic is an ancillary statistic?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

Though with the knowledge that an ancillary statistic is a statistic has distribution that is independent of the parameter, I feel like I still don't know very well for verifying a statistic is an ancillary statistic. :(

It's a problem that I got no clue to start....

Let $((X_1,Y_1),(X_2,Y_2),\ldots, (X_n,Y_n))$ be a sample from $$f_{X,Y}(x,y;\theta )=e^{-(x\theta +y/\theta )}$$

Show: $\bar{X}_n\bar{Y}_n$ is an ancillary statistic

Could anyone give me some clue to work with it? Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: For every $\theta$, with respect to the distribution $f(\ ;\ ;\theta)$, $(X_k,Y_k)$ is distributed as $(\theta^{-1}U_k,\theta V_k)$ where $(U_k,V_k)$ is i.i.d. standard exponential. Thus, $\bar X_n\bar Y_n$ is distributed as $\bar U_n\bar V_n$.

Comment: thanks a lot for the hint! So $\bar{X_{n}}$ is of $Exp({\theta })$, $\bar{Y_{n}}$ is of $Exp(\frac{1}{\theta })$. And use transformation (via Jacobian) to get the pdf of $\bar{X_{n}}\bar{Y_{n}}$?

Comment: Or....is that $\bar{U_{n}}$ and $\bar{V_{n}}$ are both standard exponential, therefore, $\bar{U_{n}}\bar{V_{n}}$ is free of $\theta$?

Comment: $\bar U_n$ and $\bar V_n$ actually have gamma distributions with shape parameter larger than $1$.  Each observation $U_k$ has an exponential distribution, so $U_1+\cdots+U_n$ has a gamma distribution, and $(U_1+\cdots+U_n)/n$ is just a rescaling of that, so it has a gamma distribution with the same shape parameter and a different scale parameter.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Yes. Is this useful to solve the question asked?

Comment: @Did : My comment answers the question that was asked in the comment above it.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I see.